# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, floating-action-button

When I installed "Floating Action Button" using nuget package in xamarin.android project then I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;" error.

I have already tried:
1. Update all nuget packages
2. Re-install all nuget packages

Installed Nuget packages are:
1. Crosslight.Xamarin.Android.Support.v4  -- v23.1.1
2. Crosslight.Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat  -- v23.1.1
3. Refractored.FloatingActionButton  --v2.1.0
4. Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotation  --v26.1.0.1
5. Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat --v26.1.0.1
6. Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI  --v26.1.0.1
7. Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView  --v26.1.0.1

Comment: @mjwills I have added packages details plz check them

Comment: Is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/ in your project?

Comment: _It worries me that **some** of your versions are 23.1.1 and some are 26.1.0.1._

Comment: @mjwills After installing Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, problem gets solved. Thanks